# In java, how should I print a string with "UTF-8" characters on windows command prompt

Tags: java

How should I print a string with "UTF-8" characters (e.g. '€')on windows command prompt?
If I use System.out.println(string) directly, it doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **System.console().writer().println()** , not System.out.println()

```
public class Test2 {
  public static final String EURO = "\u20ac";
  public static void main(String args[]){
   System.console().writer().println(EURO);
  }
}
```

You need to use an appropriate codepage for the Windows console, something like **858**. You can see what is the current codepage with the CHCP command. If needed, you switch to codepage 858 with

```
> CHCP 858
```

Finally the font used by the shell should be able to display the EURO character, use something like the Lucinda Console font.